# Visualize whitespaces using css

Tags: css

Is there some way to visualize whitespaces in text using only CSS without altering the original HTML code? Lets say the HTML is:

```
<div class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/>consectetur adipiscing elit.</div><div class="paragraph">In augue ipsum, iaculis vel dapibus ut, viverra ut tellus. In ornare euismod leo a ultrices.</div>
```

- paragraph end (¶) -> can use `:after`
- line break (↵) -> can use `:after`
- space (·) -> the only way I can think of is to prepend all spaces with something like `<span class='space' />` and the use `:after`

The last one does not fulfill the condition to use only CSS and original HTML. Is there some way to do that?

EDIT: as requested, here is CSS for the pilcrow sign after the paragarph:
`.paragraph:after { content: "¶"; }`

Comment: You should use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Could you show how you get paragraph ends and line breaks using `:after`?

Comment: I don't think this can be done without either using Javascript or modifying the HTML.

Comment: Why `<div class="paragraph">`? That's exactly what the `<p>` tag is for!

Comment: You could try to find a font that shows dots for spaces and simply change the font to that font.

Comment: @Eric custom layout engine is the reason, I don't need to bother with semantics here

Comment: @CaseyHope good point, but changing font is not the option for me

Comment: @bretik: Why is a custom font not an option?

Comment: @Eric because in this case user is the one in charge of choosing font, which will be used

Comment: There is no possible way to do this. There was a property that was in a 2007 draft, but got removed in 2010. It was called `text-replace`, and you can see more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792003/.

Answer (score 6):

javascript and php are probably easier, but if you insist on CSS you can use a custom web font and replace the space character (U+0020) with a glyph. Information for [somewhat browser compatible css](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/02/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/) and [generating custom web font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Comment: +1. However I would add that you'd need to consider the non-breaking space character as well, plus any other white space characters you display in your page. Also consider what happens if you use the `white-space:pre;` style.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this can be achieved by CSS. It's selectors ar designed to select tags, not plain text.

I recommend you to use some script replace - server or client side. You can try to use PHP [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or JavaScript [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) functions.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately there's no way to match and replace characters in CSS. I'm sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done to some extent by installing the font [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html), and then applying custom CSS rules, like so, for example, to hilight any input areas that have backspace characters in them

```
input
{
      font-family:Unifont;
}
```

For my use case, I'm using a browser extension that lets me apply custom CSS rules by domain. When I want to debug something like this, I enable the css rules for that domain and can now see if a backspace character is present in the page. From my quick tests though, it doesnt seem to show TAB characters or newline/carriage returns in any visible way.

Note that I've seen some suggest creating a font that represents control characters using [these unicode glyph representations](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf), which sounds reasonable to me ;-)

Fonts that are specifically made to show "invisible" characters, and other unicode characters [are discussed in more detail here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallback_font)

The Unicode BMP fallback font can be [downloaded here](https://scripts.sil.org/unicodebmpfallbackfont)

None of the font approaches seem to show much more thank a backspace visualized, from what i've found.

So unless a better font is found, perhaps the best way to do this is to use a chrome extension, and here are two that go in this direction:

https://github.com/chpmrc/zero-width-chrome-extension
https://github.com/glebm/render-whitespace-on-github