# How text-replace property work in css?

Tags: css

I was taking a test in upwork. There I got the following question:

> Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> body{text-replace: "a" "b" "b" "c"}
> ```
>
> What will be the output of the following string if the text replace style is implemented?
>
> **andy lives behind cafe**
>
> ---
>
> 1. ndy lives behind cbfe
> 2. cndy lives cehind ccfe
> 3. andy lives behind cafe
> 4. andy lives cehind bafe

I couldn't find any reference for the text-replace property in css.

Comment: I've never heard of this. [On Mozilla's CSS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) I can't find this property

Comment: Well it show up on google, 3:nd hit ... https://www.google.com/search?q=text-replace%3A&oq=text-replace%3A&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22text-replace%22+css

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for your try. I was searching like `text-replace css` but you searched like `"text-replace" css` which really matters. Thank you again.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Wow! You've stumbled upon a property that was last in the [2007 GCPM specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-gcpm-20070504/#character) and removed in the 2010 revision. And in an online test at that! Either the test you're taking is several years out of date, or whoever set it was just pulling from random old revisions of W3C specifications and treating them all as relevant (as users have been known to do here on Stack Overflow).

Because of how esoteric this is I'm going to just answer the question. Needless to say, this answer is provided for educational purposes only. There *is no* `text-replace` property in any current CSS specification, and there hasn't been for almost a decade (neither in [css-content](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content) nor [css-gcpm](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-gcpm)). Don't put it in your CSS and expect it to work. **It won't.** If you need to do text replacements in an HTML document, use JavaScript.

---

The answer is #2: "cndy lives cehind ccfe"

The exact CSS sample appears in the spec, linked above, and the example is described as follows (emphasis mine):

> The two rules below yield the same result. **In the first rule all ‘a’ characters are converted to ‘b’. Subsequently, all ‘b’ characters are converted to ‘c’.** In the second rule, all ‘a’ and ‘b’ characters are converted directly to ‘c’.
>
> ```
> body { text-replace: "a" "b" "b" "c" }
> body { text-replace: "a" "c" "b" "c" }
> ```

So the processing order goes:

1. andy lives behind cafe
2. **b**ndy lives behind c**b**fe
3. **c**ndy lives **c**ehind c**c**fe

Comment: I was trying hard to find the reference. Thanks.

Comment: If the question is "What will be the output of the following string..." then the correct answer would be 3 - because the CSS code will not work :)

Comment: It is 2019 and I just encountered this question in a test on fiverr. I was sure there is no text-replace property so I answered accordingly. Sad thing is that has probably cost me some points. Questions about nested pseudo-elements, marquee-speed, and image-resolution property were also.... interesting

Comment: @Steven Kuipers: You wonder if it was actually testing the user's knowledge of obscure dead specs...

Comment: So Fiverr just copy-pasted the same outdated tests from almost a decade ago in their "Tests Beta" feature... I came across this, `nav-index` (only used to work in _old versions of_ Opera), `speak` and `ruby-whatever`... Never heard of any of these until today!

Comment: @ADTC: Opera was ahead of its time with aural styles (now css-speech, which I believe is partially supported by some screen readers).