# Was the JSON <module> tag proposal ever approved/implemented?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, same-origin-policy

I've taken a test that asked questions about "JSON Module Tags" (http://www.json.org/module.html) which it looks like it was/is a proposal trying to solve the mashup security problem.

Was this proposal ever approved/implemented? I can't find any additional information about it.

PS: I have a strong impression the test was poorly built.

Comment: "PS: I have a strong impression the test was poorly built." [I wouldn't be surprised.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791921/how-text-replace-property-work-in-css)